# SFTP make copy of remote file without downloading

Tags: sftp

I have backup space that is accessible by SFTP. I have made a backup in a directory called "mybackup" on this remote storage. I would now like to make a copy of the mybackup directory called "mybackup-copy" also on the remote storage.

Is there a way to do this with SFTP that doesn't involve downloading the whole directory and then re-uploading the whole directory?

As in, if I had full SSH shell access I could do `cp -ar mybackup mybackup-copy` - can this be achieved with the sftp protocol?

Comment: Can you use `scp`? When using `scp remote_location1 remote_location2`, scp copies directly between location1 and location2, unless you use `-3` parameter. `-3` transfers files from remote 1 to the machine performing the scp command, and then to remote2. I suspect scp without `-3` might be able to do it. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html

Comment: @nobody I got hopeful on that, but no, seems that's not supported by the host. Good tip though, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A core SFTP protocol does not support copying remote files.
There's draft of [`copy-data`/`copy-file` extension to the SFTP protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00).

But in the most widespread OpenSSH SFTP server the `copy-data` is supported by very recent [version 9.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0) only. Its [`sftp` client](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp) has [`cp` command](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#cp) (but you also need a compatible server).

Another servers that do support the extensions are [ProFTPD `mod_sftp`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html) and Bitvise SFTP server.

---

So using the *shell* `cp` command is typically the only way.

Answer (score 0):

If the remote end supports `scp` this should work:

```
scp -p host:/path/to/file/filename.ext host:/path/to/copy/of/file/
```

Or, since you say you're seeking to copy a directory:

```
scp -rp host:/path/to/directory host:/path/to/copy/
```

Assuming that directory `/path/to/copy` exists on `host`, the latter command will result in a new directory `/path/to/copy/directory` on `host`.

Comment: Thanks but was asking about SFTP because SCP not available - see above.

Comment: @artfulrobot It never hurts to check, since the underlying protocol is similar.  I know I personally have deployed sites that support `sftp`, `scp` and `rsync`, since they're all based on the SSH protocol.